# onPush change detection strategy not updating values in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-changedetection

I'm learning how to use the onPush detection strategy. My view updates fine, but the variables on my child.component.ts values don't, but they do on the child.component.html

**CHILD COMPONENT**

```
@Component({
  ....
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class BdayFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() question: Question;
  @Output() nextQuestion = new EventEmitter<Question>();


  nextQuestions(): void {
    ...
    this.nextQuestion.emit(......)
    console.log(this.question);
  }
}
```

As you can see `nextQuestion`, tells the parent component to dispatch an action to get new question. I can see the next question on my HTML (let's say question #2), but when I do the `console.log(this.questions);` it prints the question #1.

**PARENT COMPONENT**

```
export class BdayShellComponent implements OnInit {
  question$: Observable<Question>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromProduct.State>) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.question$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getCurrentQuestion));
  }

  setCurrentQuestion(question: Question): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new bdayActions.SetCurrentQuestion(question));
  }
}
```

**PARENT COMPONENT HTML**

```
<app-bday-form [question]="question$ | async"
        (nextQuestion)="setCurrentQuestion($event)"></app-bday-form>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time when you put the log statement, the component didn't receive the new input.

Try the following, and you'll see the value being logged

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes.question)
  }
```